# ApiKey with role_descriptors to access Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to use the ApiKey authentication to create a reverse proxy for Kibana. The Reverse Proxy is needed to inject a custom role with some filters.

The proxy creates an ApiKey first with this post:

```
POST /_security/api_key
        {
            "name": "kb-1234-9876",
            "expiration": "1d",
            "role_descriptors": {
                "role-a": {
                    "cluster": ["all"],
                    "indices": [
                        {
                            "names": ["*"],
                            "privileges": ["read"],
                            "query": "\"bool\": { \"filter\": { \"terms\": { \"customer.id_customer\": [ \"1234\", \"9876\" ] } }}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

After that the authentication header with the APIKEY Base64 string is passed to the backend.

[image: Kibana Error]

Apparently the ApiKey does not have permission to access the Kibana Dashboard.

Is there any way to create the Kibana feature authorisation within the ApiKey as described in [Kibana Role Management API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/role-management-api-put.html)?

Some other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "old" Kibana authorisation with the applications privileges work. So my new Post of the ApiKey is like this:

```
POST /_security/api_key
    {
        "name": "kb-1234-9876",
        "expiration": "1d",
        "role_descriptors": {
            "role-a": {
                "cluster": ["all"],
                "indices": [
                    {
                        "names": ["*"],
                        "privileges": ["read"],
                        "query": "\"bool\": { \"filter\": { \"terms\": { \"customer.id_customer\": [ \"1234\", \"9876\" ] } }}"
                    }
                ],
                "applications": [
                    {
                        "application": "kibana-.kibana",
                        "privileges": [
                            "read"
                        ],
                        "resources": ["*"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   }
```